Extra domain automatically added when using REACT_APP_BASE_URL
Background:
Building react app using "npm run build"
And I define a config file like this, I want it to run both locally and on cloud server without any modification:
export const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL || "http://localhost:3000";

And I have created a .env file as suggested, defining the REACT_APP_BASE_URL as my server https://public ip, I will name it <PUB_IP> in the following, then When I call an api, I will import the BASE_URL, like this:
const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/api/messages`);

Problems:
Then the weird thing comes out, when I run this code, It will call an remote address like: https://domain/https://<PUB_IP/api/messages', the thing is, in the front end, I have even never define my domain name or provide any other information.
And If I console.log(BASE_URL), it appears to be correct, which is the <PUB_IP> I defined.
AAAAND, I tried smth:

SITUATION 1: no .env, no REACT_APP_BASE_URL defined on my server, it
will use localhost, so seems like the react app itself will not
define the REACT_APP_BASE_URL.
SITUATION 2: only define .env, still
has the extra domain in the request.
SITUATION 3: only define
REACT_APP_BASE_URL on my server, it will read the variable from the
server, and also add the extra domain.
SITUATION 4: both define .env
and set on server, the varibale in the server takes priority.
SITUATION 5: if the variable not started with REACT_APP_, it can not
be read, using localhost(I think this is clear, because it is
mentioned in the official doc that varibale should started with that)

I really takes years to figure out how this happened but failed. The really weird thing is that how the front suppose to know my domain name, since it does not even exists in the frontend code.
I only mentioned it in the nginx proxy, however, the request url generated before sent to nginx. And I also checked the nginx log that it did receved request like https://domain/https://<PUB_IP/api/messages and can not parse it successfully.
I really want to know if there is anyone else have met this problem, And do anyone have some insights about this problem. I would be really appreciated if someone would share some opinions!!
Anyone can share some similiar experience and give me some insights about my situation
Update: I find out that it is because the I defined the https://, but when it give to BASE_URL, the first colon somehow disappeared, it comes to http//, So that is why it will add my domain name automatically. But I am still confused why this colon disappeared
